# Using A Namespace In Place Of A Class

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I'm designing an interface to abstract the tasks of managing Direct3D, Direct2D, DXGI, and the associated Win32API calls.

Keep everything inside a namespace or refactor to use a class?

**WindowsApp.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

namespace WindowsApp
{
    bool Initialize(HINSTANCE instanceHandle);
}
```

**WindowsApp.cpp**

```
#include "WindowsApp.h"

namespace WindowsApp
{
    namespace
    {
        HWND ghMainWnd = 0;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;

        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        }
    }

    bool Initialize(HINSTANCE instanceHandle)
    {
        WNDCLASS wc;
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = instanceHandle;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
        wc.lpszClassName = L"BasicWndClass";

        if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"RegisterClass FAILED", 0, 0);
            return false;
        }

        ghMainWnd = CreateWindow(
            L"BasicWndClass",
            L"Win32Basic",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0,
            0,
            instanceHandle,
            0);

        if (ghMainWnd == 0)
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"CreateWindow FAILED", 0, 0);
        }

        ShowWindow(ghMainWnd, 1);
        UpdateWindow(ghMainWnd);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "WindowsApp.h"

int Run()
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };

    BOOL bRet = 1;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"GetMessage FAILED", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    // Deinitialize Here
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    if (!WindowsApp::Initialize(hInstance)) { return 0; }
    return Run();
}
```

Using a namespace allows me to hide implementation details inside the nested unnamed namespace.
A class wont let me hide things but I can make them inaccessible inside the private section, that's good enough I suppose.

Using a class runs the risk of users trying to instantiate multiple objects, which, would cause the application to crash from initializing DirectX twice or something.
Namespaces avoid this issue however they present a performance degrading factor, I have to check the `Initialized` variable during each function call. I really dislike this.

Finally using a class requires the user to pass around the instantiated object throughout the application wherever the underlying methods are needed. That is really disappointing since the namespace approach gives me access whenever I'm inside a file that's got an `#include` to the namespaces header file. I really like this.

The namespace approach seems like the best way to go but something doesn't quite sit right with me in the way variables are handled inside the nested unnamed namespace. **Is that an okay practice?** My gut is telling me no! no! no!

So I guess my question would be: **Is this an appropriate use-case for namespaces?**

For Clarification:
I've got the unnamed namespace defined inside WindowsApp.cpp along with the function definitions - forward declarations to all the functions are inside WindowsApp.h - Through use of calling these functions manipulates the variables inside the unnamed namespace. Is this a bad use of namespaces or should it be done a different way? Simply including the header file in any other .cpp gives you access to the functions and in turn the underlying data. This is very appealing. My gut tells me there is some kind of performance penalty that will ensue from structuring like this.

Comment: sounds to me like you're looking for a singleton pattern

Comment: At first glance it does. This namespace pattern sounds like the better approach granted I'm aloud to declare variables inside the nested unnamed namespace and then access them through the functions defined inside the parent named namespace. Not having to pass an instantiated class object around the application just to get access to it's member functions seems needless when you can just `#include` the file which has all the forward declarations to the namespace functions in it.

Comment: you don't necessarily have to pass an instance around everywhere, the single instance could be gotten statically `WindowsAppClass::getInstance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EDIT**: Remove stuff about unnamed namespaces begin unique to TUs now the code in the question has been clarified.]

In C++ we tend to think of a `class` as being a wrapper for some data which maintains an invariant (as opposed to a `struct`, which tends to be used for a bunch of data with no invariant). The constructor establishes the invariant, the destructor tears it down, and the member functions are careful to maintain it. Here, if I've understood correctly, it seems like your invariant is that `Initialized()` must called prior to using any other API function.

There is another alternative, which is to use so-called "magic statics", otherwise known as "Meyers singletons". Do something like the following:

```
// In WindowsApp.cpp

namespace {

class WindowsAppImpl {
public:
    WindowsAppImpl()
    {
        // Do initialization stuff here
    }

    ~WindowsAppImpl()
    { 
        // Do teardown stuff if necessary
    }

    // Example function
    int getMagicNumber()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

WindowsAppImpl& GetInstance() {
    static WindowsAppImpl instance{};
    return instance;
}

} // end private namespace

// Public function declared in WindowApp.h
int GetMagicNumber() {
    // Get the singleton instance
    WindowsAppImpl& instance = GetInstance();

    // Call member function
    return instance.getMagicNumber();
}
```

This approach adds a function which returns a reference to the singleton `WindowsAppImpl` instance. The compiler guarantees that this instance is constructed exactly once, the first time `GetInstance()` is called. (It will also run the destructor for `WindowsAppImpl` after `main()` has finished, which is probably not important in this case but can be useful in some cases.) The advantage of this approach is that inside `GetMagicNumber()` you can be sure the initialization routines have been run, without requiring the user to pass around some sort of `WindowsAppContext` instance of their own.

Comment: I've got the unnamed namespace defined inside WindowsApp.cpp along with the function definitions - forward declarations to all the functions are inside WindowsApp.h - Through use of calling these functions manipulates the variables inside the unnamed namespace. Is this a bad use of namespaces or should it be done a different way? Simply including the header file in any other .cpp gives you access to the functions and in turn the underlying data. This is very appealing. My gut tells me there is some kind of performance penalty that will ensue from structuring like this.

Comment: `in C++ we tend to think of a class as being a wrapper for some data which maintains an invariant (as opposed to a struct, which tends to be used for a bunch of data with no invariant).` Would you mind to elaborate? I'll opt out of that `*we* tend to`.

Comment: @dxiv There's almost no difference between the meaning of the `class` and `struct` keywords in the language (you could replace every usage of `class` with `struct` in the average C++ program and it would still work), so the invariant vs no invariant distinction is more like a useful convention than something strictly required by the language. Like every convention though it's not adhered to by everybody, and it's easy to find code which doesn't do this. That's why I said "we tend to"... seeing `struct` used is a strong indication there's no invariant, but (sadly) not a guarantee.

Comment: @KKlouzal Ah, okay, I understand. In this case, I'd still recommend wrapping your initialization stuff in a class (private inside `WindowsApp.h`), and using the "magic static" approach so you get guaranteed order of initialization. Global variables are bad, and particularly so in C++ as the order in which the compiler initializes them before `main()` is essentially random. Using the magic static approach at least solves the latter problem.

Comment: Declaring variables inside a namespace gives them namespace scope? This is still bad like a global? Order of initialization being random is a very bad thing. I've updated the OP with verbatim example code. However, if namespace variables are considered global(even when defined in .cpp file?) and have random order of initialization then it's a deal breaker. :( :( :(

Comment: @dxiv See also the [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c2-use-class-if-the-class-has-an-invariant-use-struct-if-the-data-members-can-vary-independently)

Comment: @TristanBrindle Structs can have constructors (or even data member initializers `struct X { int x = 42; };` since `C++11`). Structs are sometimes associated with PODs, and in [BS's own words](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#PODs) "*The most important aspect of C++11 PODs are that adding or subtracting constructors do not affect layout or performance*". Incidentally, he makes the point that a `struct` *may* have an invariant in the same breath. Not arguing nor taking sides here, just pointing that it's a matter of style and preference rather than an absolute, and will leave it at that.

Comment: @TristanBrindle Your GetInstance function doesn't return a `WindowsAppImpl`, and besides having the `Impl` being the user-facing API seems off-norm?

Comment: @KKlouzal C++ has separate notions of "storage duration" and "linkage" of variables and functions, which can be very confusing as the `static` keyword can affect both depending on where it's used! Variables declared at namespace scope always have *static* storage duration, so there's only one of them, instantiated at some point before `main()`. This is true inside an unnamed namespace too, as far as I know; the only difference is that the variable will have internal *linkage*, so you can't access it directly from another translation unit.